# Duplicate entries in a list

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have class called Rides which have a list of reservations. When I append a new reservation to the list, it will append the same reservation and create a 'duplicate'. See attached photo.

This is the code where the entry is added:

```
let reservation = RealmReservation(json: json["reservation"])
realm.add(reservation, update: true)
rides.reservations.append(reservation)
```

My code for that class is as follows:

```
class RealmReservation: Object {
dynamic var id: Int = 0

override static func primaryKey() -> String {
  return "id"
}
end
```

How do I ensure uniqueness in a List?

Thanks!

[image: Duplicate entry]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first glance, I can see three ways to address this:

1) If your class can be made Hashable, you could use a set instead of a list.  A set will manage uniqueness for you.

```
rides.reservations.insert(reservation)
```

2) You could also use a dictionary instead of a list (or in addition to it).

```
rides.reservations[reservation.primaryKey()] = reservation
```

3) You can test for an existing entry before appending to the list:

```
 if !rides.reservations.contains({ $0.primaryKey() == reservation.primaryKey() })
 { rides.reservations.append(reservation) }
```

Comment: Yea. I'm going with #3.

Answer (score 0):

A new instance of the same reservation is being appended because the primary key property `id` value is different each time.

Since you've marked that property as your Realm object's primary key, as long as the value of `id` remains the same, calling `add(_: update:)` with `update` set to `true` would update your previous object, instead of adding a new one.

My recommendation would be to check where `id` is being generated, and make sure it stays consistent for the same reservations.

Let me know if you need additional clarification! :)

Comment: My take on the OP's data is that  65416 is the only duplicate. Since 62639, 62645 and 62828 are under different parents, I deduced that this was a sublevel table (or hierarchical) so they are not actual duplications although they show similar states.

Comment: Yea. What Alain T. said